# Lua: improving a multiple words replacement with local values

Tags: string, replace, lua, gsub

I have 3 locals numbers (total, elapsedtime and percent) and a string. This string the user can use a text field to customize the order and which numbers is shown to him.
The user can type {data1} to show total, {data2} to show the elapsedtime, and {data3} for percentage.

For instance, a guy enter the text: "i got the time: {data2}, {data3}% of {data1} minutes".
The function returns: "i got the time: 1000, 20% of 5000 minutes"

I've created the function below to handle the replacement, but i am almost sure that exists a better way to achieve this result.
**So my question is how can i improve this big function?**

```
    --user typed
        local user_chose = "i got the time: {data2}, {data3}% of {data1} minutes"

    --local values for replacement
        local total = 5000
        local elapsedtime = 1000
        local percent = 20

    --replace function    
        local _data1, _data2, _data3
        local replace_func = function (data)
            if (data == "data1") then
                return _data1
            elseif (data == "data2") then
                return _data2
            elseif (data == "data3") then
                return _data3
            end
        end

        function create_text (data1, data2, data3)
--update the 3 locals used on replace_func
            _data1, _data2, _data3 = data1, data2, data3
--do the gsub
            return string.gsub ( user_chose, "{(.-)}", replace_func)
        end

    --print the string to the user
        print (create_text (total, elapsedtime, percent))
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview.se]

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160702/lua-corona-string-text/23164688#23164688

Comment: thanks for the advise, i'm new here. topic subject edited, let me known if is okey now.

Answer (score 4):

> The user can type {data1} to show total, {data2} to show the elapsedtime, and {data3} for percentage

Those are bad macro names, just as they would be bad variables names. The user should be able to type {total} to show total, {elapsedtime} to show the elapsedtime, etc.

> how can i improve this big function?

The most obvious change would be to pass a table to `gsub`, so you don't need to write the replacement function.

```
function expand(format, values)
    return (format:gsub("{(.-)}", values))
end

local usertext = "i got the time: {elapsedtime}, {percent}% of {total} minutes"
local expanded = expand(usertext, {total = 50000, elapsedtime = 1000, percent = 20})
```

If you're not adverse to extending `string` (some people find this reprehensible), you can get nicer usage syntax:

```
function string:expand(values)
    return (self:gsub("{(.-)}", values))
end

local expanded = usertext:expand { total = 50000, elapsedtime = 1000, percent = 20 }
```

If you insist on using positional macro names, you can do this:

```
function string:expand(...)
    local args = {...}
    local function getarg(i) return args[tonumber(i)] end
    return (self:gsub('{data(%d+)}', getarg))
end
local usertext = "i got the time: {data2}, {data3}% of {data1} minutes"
local expanded = usertext:expand(50000, 1000, 20)
```

Comment: Awesome, so, i've played with your functions a little bit and tried to add a extra replacement if the user wants to add a custom value by him self, can you tell me if this is the correct Approach or there are other standard way to do that?                       `function string:expand (...)
local args = {...}
local function getarg (i)
local n = tonumber (i)
if (n) then
return args[tonumber(i)] 
else
return loadstring (i)()
end
end
return (self:gsub('{data(%d+)}', getarg):gsub ('{func(.-)}', getarg))
end

print ("{data3} speed: {func return 123456} ({data1}, {data2})":expand (50000, 1000, 20))`